# Porting typed arrays from Android to iPhone app

Tags: java, android, iphone, objective-c

I have to port my Android app to iPhone and I am wondering what would be the alternatives - if any - to port the typed arrays.

The main issue is readability, no so much type enforcement - as there are answers to this already available. However they are quite "cumbersome" comparing to a simple `NSMutableArray *` or `NSMutableDictionary`declaration.

So basically if I have sth like this in Java:

```
initAllCustomers(List<Countries> allCountries, List<Nationalities> allNationalities, Hashtable<Integer, Job> allJobPossibilities)
```

Looks like this:

```
- (id)initAllCustomers: (NSMutableArray *) allCountries allNationalities: (NSMutableArray *) allNationalities allJobPossibilities: (NSMutableDictionary *)allJobPossibilities;
```

Now looking at the iPhone code one has no idea about the elements in the Arrays or Dictionaries - which makes the code far less readable. (more text with less information unfortunately)

Is there any way to solve this without introducing lots of (typing and execution speed) overhead?
Since I have quite many different and large structures like this.

Comment: I think its quite reasonable that an argument, taking an array thats called allNationalities might contain Nationalities objects. Then there's always commenting, of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS code is probably less readable to you because you come from an Android background. If you have been looking at lines of code like that for years, it is completely normal. In the other seat, me looking at the Java code finds it enormously verbose in this situation.

If you want to port to iOS, you have two options in this situation:

1. Port to iOS
2. Don't Port to iOS

Option 1 means, use the native Cocoa frameworks as you have tried NSMutableArray for example (Should probably NSArray in your example by the way).

Option 2 means, use C++ and C. The STL allows you to use typed variables as you seem to feel is important.

Also, this code makes me nervous about what exactly you are initializing here. Is it a database of some sort? You might want to look at CoreData.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment - in fact I do iPhone development for couple of years already and still did not get used to it ;-) I was just wondering if there is anything that I have missed.Thanks for your interesting idea aboz C++